# How to interpret drift between 2 images, using the function normxcorr2 in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, cross-correlation

I am a beginner in Matlab and I need to remove the drift (which exists because of the microscope when capturing the images at different time) betw my two images so that they can be comparable. I wanted to calculate the drift by cross-correlating the 4 corners of my two images.
To identify my drift, I found this code using the function normxcorr2 :

```
c = normxcorr2(picture1,picture2);
[max_c, imax] = max(abs(c(:))); %find the max value 
[ypeak, xpeak] = ind2sub(size(c),imax(1)); %Find peak in cross-correlation.
corr_offset = round([(xpeak-(size(c,2)+1)/2) (ypeak-(size(c,1)+1)/2)]);
offset = corr_offset;
xoffset = offset(1);
yoffset = offset(2);
```

and I found the following results :

```
xpeak=195
ypeak=136
max_c=0.7250
offset=[-1,1]
xoffset=-1
yoffset=-1
```

I am a bit confused about how to interpret these results. Does it mean there is a drift of -0.7250 in the direction y and -0.7250 in the direction x? Is this result in pixel or meter?

Here are my two pictures :
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X41r3.png)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CAzS.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `max_c` is the *correlation* of the two images when they are aligned as best as possible. The `xoffset` and `yoffset` are the shifts in the x and y direction

Comment: Thank Suever for your reply. So if I want to remove the drift from the position x- and y- on my picture2 to compare them with my picture1, what should I substract? -1 in the direction x and -1 in the direction y or -0.7250? Also, do you think I should use the function xcorr2 instead of normxcorr2?

Comment: @Suever do you agree?

Comment: Did you read my comment? `max_c` is the **correlation** *not* the shift. You should subtract `xoffset` and `yoffset`. I'm not sure how I can make that any clearer.

Comment: Ok thank you again. Is the calculated offset in pixels?

Comment: Yes it is pixels.

Comment: @Suever do you know another method to obtain the drift between my two images, with a sub-pixel accuracy? thank you

Comment: Depending on how your images look, I'd suggest looking at this example: https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html

Comment: Thank you @akamath  !! This example seems to be exactly what I'd need, but I have the error message "matchedPoints1 and matchedPoints2 do not have enough points." I guess I have to find something else... I add the pictures in my question so that you can see how they are like.

Comment: I think I found a way to replace the step 3, by using a particle tracking code able to pair my beads location, and then I used the example code (from step 4) to find geometric transformation betw. my images. My question is, how could I also correct the translation? Because as
` scaleRecovered = sqrt(ss*ss + sc*sc)
thetaRecovered = atan2(ss,sc)*180/pi `

tx and ty (the translations) are not taken into account for the recovered image.
thank you for your help